# Keyboard shortcut for the next/previous video in a playlist in YouTube TV

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts, youtube-playlist

I use the [YouTube TV interface](http://youtube.com/tv) a lot. However, I can't figure out how to skip to the next/previous video in a playlist and <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
 <kbd>N or P</kbd> doesn't work. Is there a keyboard shortcut (or a user script that adds a keyboard shortcut) for this task?

Comment: The lack of a keyboard shortcut feels like a strange omission. Also, TIL you can use the YouTube TV interface through a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semicolon I think. Try that out and see if it works. It works for me on my PS3.

Comment: This works for going to the next video, but how about the previous one?